# How to specify character encoding for 7z?

Tags: locale, 7z

Doing `7z x` on an archive gives me

```
'20 ª.1 ¯® '$'\302\212''¨à®¢®£à ¤áª ï ã«.rtf'  IMG_6527.JPG
''$'\302\212''¨à®¢®£à ¤áª ï, ¨áâ.doc'          IMG_6532.JPG
''$'\302\204''®¯  á®£« è¥­¨¥(3).doc'           IMG_6542.JPG
''$'\302\204\302\212\302\217''.doc'        IMG_6543.JPG IMG_6526.JPG
```

Clearly some files were encoded differently and `7z` by default does not convert to UTF-8. How to tell `7z` to do the conversion?

The only options I found for charset:

> `-scc{UTF-8|WIN|DOS}`: set charset for for console input/output
> `-scs{UTF-8|UTF-16LE|UTF-16BE|WIN|DOS|{id}}`: set charset for list files

`WIN`, `DOS`, `UTF-8` do not work. When trying to guess charset via

```
7z -scsCP1251 l 26-08-2016_10-18-14.zip
```

7z gives warning:

```
Unsupported charset: cp1251
```

`unzip` does this right (cyrillic symbols got converted):

```
'20 к.1 по Кировоградская ул.rtf'  IMG_6532.JPG  'Доп  соглашение(3).doc'
26-08-2016_10-18-14.zip        IMG_6542.JPG  'Кировоградская, ист.doc'
IMG_6526.JPG               IMG_6543.JPG
IMG_6527.JPG               ДКП.doc
```

Supplementary information

- p7zip Version:

  ```
  15.14.1 (locale=ru_RU.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,4 CPUs AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 960T Processor (100FA0),ASM)
  ```
- hexdump of start of archive (`od -tx1z -Ax`):

  ```
  000000 50 4b 03 04 14 00 00 00 00 00 81 54 1a 49 7e 35  >PK.........T.I~5<
  000010 fa 34 00 ec 00 00 00 ec 00 00 07 00 17 00 84 8a  >.4..............<
  000020 8f 2e 64 6f 63 75 70 13 00 01 19 fd 45 54 d0 94  >..docup.....ET..<
  000030 d0 9a d0 9f 2e 64 6f 63 00 00 00 00 d0 cf 11 e0  >.....doc........<
  000040 a1 b1 1a e1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
  000050 00 00 00 00 3e 00 03 00 fe ff 09 00 06 00 00 00  >....>...........<
  000060 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 71 00 00 00  >............q...<
  000070 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 73 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  >........s.......<
  000080 fe ff ff ff 00 00 00 00 70 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff  >........p.......<
  000090 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  >................<
  *
  000230 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ec a5 c1 00  >................<
  000240 07 80 19 04 00 00 f0 12 bf 00 00 00 00 00 00 10  >................<
  000250 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 72 7b 00 00 0e 00 62 6a  >........r{....bj<
  000260 62 6a 2a 16 2a 16 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >bj*.*...........<
  000270 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 19 04 16 00 34 8e 00 00  >............4...<
  000280 48 7c 00 00 48 7c 00 00 4b 2c 00 00 00 00 00 00  >H|..H|..K,......<
  000290 19 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
  0002a0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff ff 0f 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
  0002b0 00 00 00 00 ff ff 0f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
  0002c0 ff ff 0f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
  0002d0 00 00 00 00 b7 00 00 00 00 00 3e 0e 00 00 00 00  >..........>.....<
  0002e0 00 00 3e 0e 00 00 a0 1b 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 1b  >..>.............<
  0002f0 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 1b 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 1b  >................<
  000300 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 1b 00 00 14 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
  000310 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00 b4 1b  >................<
  000320 00 00 00 00 00 00 b4 1b 00 00 00 00 00 00 b4 1b  >................<
  000330 00 00 38 00 00 00 ec 1b 00 00 84 00 00 00 70 1c  >..8...........p.<
  000340 00 00 34 00 00 00 b4 1b 00 00 00 00 00 00 b8 28  >..4............(<
  000350 00 00 e6 01 00 00 a4 1c 00 00 00 00 00 00 a4 1c  >................<
  000360 00 00 00 00 00 00 a4 1c 00 00 00 00 00 00 a4 1c  >................<
  000370 00 00 00 00 00 00 a4 1c 00 00 00 00 00 00 d8 1d  >................<
  000380 00 00 00 00 00 00 d8 1d 00 00 00 00 00 00 d8 1d  >................<
  000390 00 00 00 00 00 00 43 28 00 00 02 00 00 00 45 28  >......C(......E(<
  0003a0 00 00 00 00 00 00 45 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 45 28  >......E(......E(<
  *
  0003c0 00 00 00 00 00 00 45 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 9e 2a  >......E(.......*<
  0003d0 00 00 a2 02 00 00 40 2d 00 00 da 00 00 00 45 28  >......@-......E(<
  0003e0 00 00 2d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >..-.............<
  0003f0 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 1b 00 00 00 00 00 00 d8 1d  >................<
  000400 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
  000410 00 00 00 00 00 00 d8 1d 00 00 00 00 00 00 d8 1d  >................<
  000420
  ```

Comment: It's difficult to reproduce the problem without a copy of the problematic archive.  Can you show the commands you used to create it?

Comment: It's a zip archive created on Windows 7 by different person. He sent it to me for printing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the encoding used to create the zip file, you might be able to prevent unwanted translations by temporarily setting the locale to "C":

```
LC_ALL=C 7z x $archive
```

(This helped for a zip created by IZArc on Win7, using two of your example filenames.)

However, for the archive in the question, the "filename" field contains the CP1251 encoding of "ДКП.doc" (`84 8a 8f 2e 64 6f 63`).  The "extra" field uses an Info-zip extension (see section 4.6.9 of the [Zip Specification v 6.3.4](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) ) to store the UTF-8 filename.  `unzip` knows about this header, and uses the UTF-8 name, ignoring the CP1251 one.

`7z` doesn't do anything with this "extra field", and only uses the CP1251 one.  Depending on the current locale, it might create the file using that exact name (the raw bytes `84 8a 8f`), or worse, treat them as unicode points to be expanded to UTF-8 first (`c2 84 c2 8a c2 8f`).

One option is to use external utilities to change the `zip` first:

```
#!/bin/bash

cp orig.zip renamed.zip

index=0
zipinfo -1 orig.zip | while read name ; do
        ziptool renamed.zip rename $index "$name"
        index=$((index+1))
done
```

[`ziptool`](https://nih.at/libzip/ziptool.html) is from [libzip](https://nih.at/libzip/).  `zipinfo` is distributed with [Info-ZIP's UnZip](http://www.info-zip.org/UnZip.html), so you might as well have just used `unzip`.

Comment: This does not work. Gives me the same result. I suspect file paths were stored with CP1251 charset. But you're using UTF-8.

Comment: This answer works for zips that store only UTF-8; the hexdump shows that the OP's zip contains the CP1251 encoding, followed by the UTF-8 encoding using Info-zip extensions (see https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT 4.6.9).

Comment: So then the question is how to make 7z use utf-8 version of filename? Is it not capable?

Comment: @pusheax Not with current 7z, no.  Added a possible workaround, although by that point, it's simpler to stick with `unzip`.

Comment: I think you're right. That is unfortunate. Always thought 7z is superior.

Comment: @pusheax The 7z *format* has its advantages, and the 7z tool is well-suited for handling that.  But it's not the best for other formats and their vendor-specific extensions.

Answer (score 2):

I've found this discussion thread with the author of `p7zip`, Igor Pavlov, on p7zip's page: [OEM charset issues in Linux](https://sourceforge.net/p/p7zip/discussion/383044/thread/3d213124/). It's a twin of this Q&A. This post says it all.

> Probably -mcp switch doesn't work in p7zip. But -mcp works in 7-zip
>   (Windows version). So now I don't know how to make it working for
>   p7zip. the function: Rusting MultiByteToUnicodeString(const AString
>   &srcString, UINT codePage) in CPP\Common\StringConvert.cpp

It's dated 2016-04-18. I checked the latest p7zip release from July and the switch is still missing. At least in documentation, as I didn't test.

Answer (score 2):

Checked P7ZIP 16.02 [64-bit] (Xubuntu /Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS)

Cyrillic characters are still a problem:

- Can unpack - content is OK, name when unpacked is corrupted.
- Cannot easily work with the files, when they are not yet archived.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

OEM code page selection is broken in both vanilla unzip and vanilla p7zip.
I made a [patch](https://github.com/mate-desktop/engrampa/issues/5#issuecomment-659165691) fixing this issue and there is [ppa for Ubuntu](https://github.com/mate-desktop/engrampa/issues/5#issuecomment-649217455) with p7zip with this patch applied. Those patches also support manual code page setting with OEMCP env variable.

Answer (score 1):

use `7z -scs1251 l 26-08-2016_10-18-14.zip`

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for an hour or more I found that WinRar has a built-in option for that (Options -> Name encoding). Try it:
https://www.win-rar.com/